# mysql query returns an empty result set

Tags: mysql

I have been tasked with a query I am having problems with. Here is the query:

> Given a user id and a month, produce a list containing student name, list of files they own (largest to smallest) including total number of files and number of bytes used in a month specified.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(Select * from htmp_cs368 
Join roster_cs368 ON htmp_cs368.userId =
 roster_cs368.lastName Where htmp_cs368.userId = 
(SELECT lastName FROM roster_cs368 WHERE userId = 'userId' AND htmp_cs368.monthIn = 'monthIn')) 
UNION 
(Select * from atmp_cs368 
JOIN roster_cs368 ON atmp_cs368.userId = 
roster_cs368.userId Where roster_cs368.userId = 
'userId' AND atmp_cs368.monthIn = 'monthIn') ORDER BY fileSize DESC;
```

I am getting a result of empty set. My tables are full. I am hoping somone can correct my mistakes.

I have included my schema:

```
mysql> select * from roster_cs368
-> ;
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| userId | firstName | lastName  |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| apn7cf | Allen     | Newton    |
| atggg3 | andrew    | goebel    |
```

Primary key is userId

```
mysql> select * from htmp_cs368;
+------------+----------+------------+----------+----------+-------+------+-------+----------------------+
| filePerms  | numLinks | userId     | idGroup  | fileSize | monthIn | day  | time  | fileName             |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+----------+-------+------+-------+----------------------+
| drwx------ |        2 | schulte    | faculty  |      289 | Nov   |    7 | 2011  | Java                 |
| -rw-r--r-- |        1 | schulte    | faculty  |      136 | Apr   |   29 | 2012  | LD                   |
| drwxr-xr-x |        3 | schulte    | faculty  |      177 | Mar   |   20 | 2012  | Upgrade              |
```

No primary key here

```
 select * from atmp_cs368;
+------------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
| filePerms  | numLinks | userId       | idGroup  | fileSize | monthIn | day  | time  | fileName                    |
+------------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
| drwxr-xr-x |        2 | remierm      | 203      |      245 | Sep   |   17 | 14:40 | 148360_sun_studio_12        |
| drwx---rwx |       31 | antognolij   | sasl     |     2315 | Oct   |   24 | 12:28 | 275                         |
| -rwx------ |        1 | kyzvdb       | student  |       36 | Sep   |   19 | 13:05 | 275hh                       |
```

No primary key here as either.

I have had very little experience with mysql. I also have to come up with:
If no user id is specified, all files, if no month specified, all users and if neither specified, all months and users.
I am stuck and at a lost. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Are these userid connected with each anyhow? Just want to make sure as you don't have any key links with other tables and I dont see similar userID in any table.

Comment: First, I'm wondering why this question has `java` tag. Second, every table should have primary key! So...consider creating tables in right way, before asking why your query doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you comparing use rid with last name? Also, remove the brackets from around each dude of the union

Comment: @brano88 Java servlets, thats why. OP edited my tags.

Comment: I can't see any Java code...but nevermind. Focus on creating tables in right way, this time with primary keys,foreign keys and with right referential integrity too. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a number of problems in the SQL.

First

```
Join roster_cs368 ON htmp_cs368.userId = roster_cs368.lastName
```

You try to join the `userId` field to the `lastName` field, which definitely won't work.  It should be `userId` in both tables.

Then

```
WHERE userId = 'userId' AND htmp_cs368.monthIn = 'monthIn'
```

Assuming those really are literal strings, they won't match anything in the table.  You need to use a parameterized query, and substitute question marks in the SQL, as in

```
WHERE userId = ? AND htmp_cs368.monthIn = ?
```

and provide the actual values to be used in the Java code.

I think you're looking for something along these lines (untested, but this will give you a starting point)

List of files

```
select r.lastName, r.firstName, t.fileName, t.fileSize
    from htmp_cs368 t join roster_cs368 r on t.userId=r.userId
    where t.userId=? and t.monthIn=?
    order by fileSize desc
```

Summary:

```
select r.lastName, r.firstName, count(t.fileName), sum(t.fileSize)
    from htmp_cs368 t join roster_cs368 r on t.userId=r.userId
    where t.userId=? and t.monthIn=?
    group by t.userId
```

This is a simple approach that does not take into account files appearing and disappearing *during* a month, but you don't seem to have data in your tables for this.

Also, it's not clear what `atmp_cs368` is for, or why the `time` column in one table seems to have `year` values.

Comment: Unless last names are sometimes used as userids - it is possible, if not unlikely

Comment: Given the appearance of `userId` in both tables, it is _highly_ unlikely.

Comment: @JimGarrison atmp_cs368 and htmp_cs368 are textfiles from "sreen shots" on our unix system.

Comment: What is the difference between the contents of the tables name `htmp_cs368` and `atmp_cs368`.  These are table names as shown in the `select` statements in your question.

Comment: @JimGarrison atmp_cs368 are from our "admiral" server and htmp_cs368 are from our "hoare" server. The biggest difference is fileName and user names. Some of us have access to both servers, some don't. It is just an excercise my professor has for us. It is more about servlets only for some reason he comes up with "gawd" awful queries where half of our class has not had the database course yet. The query experience I have had has been VERY simple stuff. Single line stuff. I appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others you seem to have a number of problems in your SQL. I dont think it can compile as well.

Try:

```
SELECT   r.userId, files.* 
FROM     roster_cs368 AS r
JOIN     (
          Select * from htmp_cs368 WHERE userId = 'userId' AND monthIn = 'monthIn'
          UNION 
          Select * from atmp_cs368 Where userId = 'userId' AND monthIn = 'monthIn'
         ) AS files ON files.userId = r.userId
ORDER BY files.fileSize DESC;
```

You need only one `JOIN`. This lists users and all their files. And take care to equate apples to apples (userId != lastName).

Now to get count of files and file sizes etc you need a `GroupBy` effectively. But you cannot list files and get count of files together "easily". It will have to be one way or other. Just for the count you can use Jim's solution.

Answer (score 0):

This JOIN looks a tad suspicious...

```
JOIN roster_cs368 ON htmp_cs368.userId = roster_cs368.lastName
```

Even if `userId` in `htmp_cs368` has an equivalent value in the `lastName` column of `roster_cs368`, this is very bad form. JOINS should typically be done on like-named columns.

If these two columns are unrelated (it's hard to tell when `roster_cs368` also has a `userId` column), then that would be at least part of your problem.

Also, `htmp_cs368.monthIn = 'monthIn'` doesn't make sense. This won't match anything in that column either.